# How to add clicable a href to attachment of email sended from javax.mail

Tags: java, email, mime, mime-mail

I am sending email from javax.mail.

I am sending attachments (some files, for example PDF.)

I want to add link to attachment to email body like this:

> Dear user, you can download your file in attachment by this link
>   "DOWNLOAD"

My code is:

```
    String cidLinks = "<br>";
    int counter = 0;
    for (String attachments : email.pathToAttachments) {
        String cidData = "<data" + (counter) + ">";
        MimeBodyPart mimeBodyPart = buildMimeBodyPart(attachments, cidData);
        multipart.addBodyPart(mimeBodyPart);
        counter++;
        cidLinks += "<a href='cid:" + cidData + "'> " + mimeBodyPart.getFileName() + "</a>" + "<br>";
    }
```

And MimeBuilder is:

```
private MimeBodyPart buildMimeBodyPart(String path, String id) {
    MimeBodyPart emailMemeBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    try {
        DataSource source = new FileDataSource(path);
        emailMemeBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
        emailMemeBodyPart.setFileName(source.getName());
        emailMemeBodyPart.setContentID(id);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Err: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return emailMemeBodyPart;
}
```

I have problems with links generated in:

```
cidLinks += "<a href='cid:" + cidData + "'> " + mimeBodyPart.getFileName() + "</a>" + "<br>";
```

When i click on link in email, it not start download a file.

Files in attachments are sucessfuly sended.

Can you help me? Where is a problem? How can I download file from attachment by link?

Thank you.

Note: email content is valid hmtl format.

Comment: So what does happen when you click the link? When you look at the source of the email, is the CID correct? Have you tried using CID links for embedded images? If I remember correctly, that's the point of CIDs, since you can just tell the mail client to save attachments anyway, with no need for a download link.

Comment: It will open link in new tab "cid:data0"

Comment: How can I check if cid data are correct?